# Splitting $10$ objects in three groups of sizes $4$, $4$, and $2$

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $10$ objects be split into three groups containing $4$, $4$, and $2$ objects?

Comment: My guess is 10!/(4!*4!*2!). I am not sure though.

Comment: incorporate your guess into the question. This might satisfy those voting to close; it can't hurt.

Comment: The answer depends on whether the groups are "distinguishable".  Of course the group of size 2 can be distinguished from the groups of size 4, but can we distinguish the two groups of size 4?

Answer (score 4):

If we first select the 2-bin then the two 4-bins:
$$
\frac{10\cdot 9}{2!} \frac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6 \cdot 5}{4!}\frac{4!}{4!} = \frac{10!}{2(4!)^2} = 3150
$$
The denominators remove the repetitions by permutation.

This assumes that the two 4-size bins are distinguished, if not (as fellow user @string noticed in the comments), the possibilities have to be halved to:
$$
\frac{10!}{4(4!)^2} = 1575
$$

Comment: The $4$-bins can be interchanged to no effect ...

Comment: Double counting of the $4$-bins if the bins are not distinguishable (as I expect here).